# How to get month name from date in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, extract, alter

I have added a column name `month_added`, I run the query to extract the month from the `date_added` column in my table but I get an error:

> ERROR:  column "date_added" does not exist
> LINE 1: SELECT date_added, DATENAME (MONTH, date_added)
> ^
> SQL state: 42703
> Character: 8

[image]

```
ALTER TABLE movies
ADD month_added VARCHAR (50);

UPDATE movies
SET month_added = MONTH(date_added);
```

I have also tried the EXTRACT date function

Comment: If the column `date_added` exists, you may not want add another column `month_added`, because it would violate normalization rules, and can be calculated any time by the UI tier.

Comment: The "Line1" you quoted does not look as if it has a `From` part?

Comment: _"How to get month name from date in Sql Server"_ `Select DateName(mm, dateColumn) From yourTable;` - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8fbf1/1  -- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: *"I have also tried the EXTRACT date function"* - there is no such function in SQL Server, except for Multidimensional Expressions in 2022

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to get month name from date in SQL Server

You can use the `DateName` (`tsql`) function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

```
Select DateName(Month, dateColumn) From test;
```

See also the linked SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8fbf1/2

Comment: For the sake of clarity why not just use `month` instead of `mm`

Comment: Yes, looks better @Stu